# Golang manipulating object inside a sync.Map

Tags: go

I am trying to manipulate a golang sync.Map of sync.Map, but I have some issues with the casting.
I have the following code:

```
func (cluster *Cluster) action(object1, object2 MyObject) {
                value, _ := cluster.globalMap.LoadOrStore(object1.name, sync.Map{})
                localMap := value.(sync.Map)
                localMap.Store(object2.Name, object2)
                
                value2, _ := cluster.resourceInflight.Load(node.Name)
                forComparison := value2.(sync.Map)
                fmt.Println(localMap.Load(object2.Name))
                fmt.Println(forComparison.Load(object2.Name))
}
```

```
{myObject  map[] map[]} true
<nil> false
```

I am doing this since I wish to keep the content of localMap thread safe.

The problem is I am expecting to have the same result for my two print, as "forComparison" should be  pointing to the same object than "localMap".  But second result is nil.

I am suspecting that the problem is coming from the casting of the interface "value" into an actual "sync.Map". But I am not sure how I can actually call the .Store method with inline casting.

I thought about Storing localMap inside cluster.globalMap, but this seems incorrect to me as it would break the whole point of using a localSyncMap and create concurrency issues.

Any input on what I should do ?

Comment: Most likely, you'll have an easier time just using a regular `map` of `map` and protecting with proper use of a [`Mutex` or `RWMutex`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync).

Comment: It seems you are having a state error (the state of the program is not what you expect it to be at some point in time), but only offer a small snippet of code with many undefined symbols, and no clues of how the state changes throughout the program. In other words, we couldn't know why you are getting the result you are getting.

Comment: You need to use a pointer to `sync.Map` (passing by value [will not work as you expect](https://go.dev/play/p/93ReQxhGGIL)). Agree with above - [docs state](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) "Most code should use a plain Go map instead, with separate locking or coordination..."

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed because I forgot to use a pointer. I will also consider using manual locking system !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments the issue was that you were copying a `sync.Map`; the following code will fail (output "Not found" - [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/93ReQxhGGIL)):

```golang
var sm sync.Map
var x interface{}
x = sm
sm2 := x.(sync.Map)
sm2.Store("test", "test")
result, ok := sm.Load("test")
if ok {
    fmt.Printf("Found: %s\n", result)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Not found\n")
}
```

Whereas using a pointer works as expected:

```golang
var sm sync.Map
var x interface{}
x = &sm
sm2 := x.(*sync.Map)
sm2.Store("test", "test")
result, ok := sm.Load("test")
if ok {
    fmt.Printf("Found: %s\n", result)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Not found\n")
}
```

Running `go vet` would probably have warned you about other issues (`sync.Map` contains a [`sync.Mutex`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) and these "must not be copied after first use").

Note that the docs for Sync.Map state:

> The Map type is specialized. Most code should use a plain Go map instead, with separate locking or coordination, for better type safety and to make it easier to maintain other invariants along with the map content.